# Ruby: Sort an array with an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I want to sort an array of objects by the objects last_name, but always put a certain object in the first position of the array.
To achieve that I already tried a lot but always failed with the resulting structure of the array. Here is one of my tries which fails because I can't run any methods on the resulting array objects (e.g. `@team.each do |m| puts m.username end` fails):

```
if @team = UserGroup.find_by_name("team").users.sort_by(&:last_name)
  if first_member = @team.detect{|m| m.username == "test"}
    @team.unshift @team.reject{|m| m.username == "test"}
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SQL's ORDER BY capabilities, faster than Ruby (btw, you should use `find_by_attribute!`). Untested, but play with something like this:

```
@team = UserGroup.find_by_name!("team").users.
  order("username = 'test' DESC, last_name ASC")
```

Of course you can use Ruby with the same idea:

```
@team = UserGroup.find_by_name!("team").users.
  sort_by { |u| [u.username == 'test' ? 0 : 1, u.last_name] }
```

Comment: I have to agree, your solution ist even better and faster. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@team = UserGroup.find_by_name("team").users.sort_by(&:last_name)
first_member = @team.select{|m| m.username == "test"}
@team = first_member + (@team - first_member)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. Solutions can be that simple. :) It even works when there is no user "test", great!

Comment: It's ok because it solves the problem the way the OP intended, but note you can include `m.username == 'test'` in the `sort_by`, it would be shorter and faster.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right, this should work:

```
@team = UserGroup.find_by_name("team").users.sort_by(&:last_name)
test=nil
@team=@team.delete_if {|obj| obj.username == "test" ? (test=obj; true) : false}
@team.insert(0, test)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This might work as well, but I'll use Matzi's solution for it simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question's title: "Sort an array with an exception":

the exception here is 13, so it gets always highest rank:

```
(1..15).to_a.shuffle.sort { |a,b| a == 13 ? -1 : b == 13 ? 1 : a <=> b }
```

outputs in irb:

```
=> [13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15]
```

also works with username if needed:

```
%w{mike bob mario toad test}.sort {|a,b| a == 'test' ? -1 : b == 'test' ? 1 : a <=> b }
=> ["test", "bob", "mario", "mike", "toad"]
```